# HTML to customize a product

Tags: html, css, list

I am looking to create a customizable product that you can change and see the visual changes on the site. I'm finding this hard to explain, so I apologize if you immediately know of a tutorial for this. I'm just at a loss of how to really explain this idea.

```
http: //bit. ly/L8DfF2
```

On the page it shows the product they sell, a custom xbox 360 controller, can someone point me in the right direct of how to create a custom product page with this idea.

Just glancing at the source it looks like obviously drop down lists with each option connected to a picture that changes a certain component of the product. But is there anything else more to it? I'm use to connecting listed or bulletined options to links, do I just simply connect it to the picture? Just not sure how to set up a product to display the updated options you can select is my biggest question.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's the base image, and then on top of it is a stack of empty images. As you change the settings, each has some onChange listener, that changes the `src` or one of those empty images...thereby changing the overall stacked image.

Here is some sample code on the concept...in your implementation each select would adjust a different image (that represents just the relevant piece of the product):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#shell {width:100px;height:100px;display:block; background-color:#f00;}
#button {width:50px;height:50px;display:block; background-color:#00f;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="shell"><div id="button"></div></div>
Shell:
<select onChange="col('shell',this.value)">
<!-- in your version the values below would be file names of images -->
<option value="#f00">Red</option>
<option value="#0f0">Green</option>
<option value="#00f">Blue</option>
</select><br/>
Button:
<select onChange="col('button', this.value)">
<!-- in your version the values below would be file names of images -->
<option value="#00f">Blue</option>
<option value="#f00">Red</option>
<option value="#0f0">Green</option>
</select>

<script>
function col(part,x){
    document.getElementById(part).style.backgroundColor=x;
    //in yours, it would be document.getElementById(part).src=x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So to have another set of options do I need another "fuction col(x){" set with it renamed to something else or do I just create another <select id>? guessing another '<select id> and the <div id=main> is your main overall product that you are customizing with  the different <select id>'s? Thanks btw!

Comment: I edited the code...you don't need another function for each, now it just accepts a parameter so it knows what element to act on. But you do need a new select for each piece (I guess you could do one select for WHICH piece, and another for the options as another method...) but if all of the pieces had different options, you'd then need to modify that second list on the fly, so you can decide where you want to put in the work...oh, one other clarification, if yours, you'll be using images, not divs (search for 'preview' in the code of that site to see their stack)